# Inserting data into multiple access tables at once in C# (OLEDB)

Tags: c#-4.0, oledb, ms-access-2010, insert-into, ms-access

I have created a class that will manage connection and commands, I named it **DbConfiguration** and it uses a Singleton pattern(using `dbc` as an object name).

My problem is this SQL syntax throws an error when I try to run `ExecuteNonQuery()`

Using this connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;dbms.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
```

I executed this first:

```
dbc.SetCommand("INSERT INTO inventory ([CallNumber], [Title], [ImageLocation]) VALUES (@CALLNUMBER, @TITLE, @IMAGELOC);");
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Add("@CALLNUMBER", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255);
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Add("@TITLE", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255);
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Add("@IMAGELOC", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255);

dbc.GetCommand().Parameters["@CALLNUMBER"].Value = txtCallNumber.Text;
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters["@TITLE"].Value = txtTitle.Text;
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters["@IMAGELOC"].Value = (!moveto.Equals("db_storage\\") ? moveto : "db_storage\\no_img.png");
```

and followed by:

```
dbc.GetCommand().ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Next is I executed this code:

```
dbc.SetCommand("INSERT INTO publishing_info ([ID], [Author], [DateTime], [Publisher], [Pages], [ISBN_NO]) " +
               "VALUES (" +
               "SELECT([ID] FROM inventory " +
               "WHERE inventory.CallNumber=@CALLNUMBER AND inventory.Title=@TITLE AND inventory.ImageLocation=@IMAGELOC), " +
               "@AUTHOR, @DATETIME, @PUBLISHER, @PAGES, @ISBN);");
```

and also followed by:

```
dbc.GetCommand().ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here are the parameters that I have used for your reference:

```
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Add("@AUTHOR", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255);
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Add("@DATETIME", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255);
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Add("@PUBLISHER", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255);
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Add("@PAGES", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.UnsignedInt, 4);
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Add("@ISBN", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255);

dbc.GetCommand().Parameters["@AUTHOR"].Value = txtAuthor.Text;
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters["@DATETIME"].Value = txtYear.Text;
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters["@PUBLISHER"].Value = txtPublisher.Text;
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters["@PAGES"].Value = uint.Parse(txtPages.Text);
dbc.GetCommand().Parameters["@ISBN"].Value = txtISBN.Text;
```

Here is the screenshot of my stack trace(I can't attach it because I only have 1 rep points)
http://i44.tinypic.com/2w49t84.png

What should I do to make the syntax work?
And also do I need to close the connection first before executing another query?

*Update 1*

I used `DMax(\"[ID]\", \"inventory\")` to retrieve the last `ID` but it returns all the fields of `inventory` and writes it all on the fields that it can be written to, in my C# code but if I write the query on MS Access 2010 it doesn't do what it does on a C# code. What seems to be the problem?

*Update 2*

Problem solved with `dbc.GetCommand().Parameters.Clear()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to close the connection, but you do need to insert a left parenthesis in your sub-select:

```
dbc.SetCommand("INSERT INTO publishing_info ([ID], [Author], [DateTime], [Publisher], [Pages], [ISBN_NO]) " +
           "VALUES (" +
           "(SELECT([ID] FROM inventory " +
           "WHERE inventory.CallNumber=@CALLNUMBER AND inventory.Title=@TITLE AND inventory.ImageLocation=@IMAGELOC), " +
           "@AUTHOR, @DATETIME, @PUBLISHER, @PAGES, @ISBN);");
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I found the problem access doesn't understand `SELECT` inside `VALUES`. Is there a way I can retrieve the last inserted ID?

Comment: I used `DMax(\"[ID]\", \"inventory\")` but it returns all the fields of `inventory` and writes it all on the fields that it can be written to, in my C# code but if I write the query on MS Access 2010 it doesn't do what it does on a C# code. What seems to be the problem?